# Select largest label value in Prometheus query

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I have a Prometheus and Grafana instance set up where I want to query a specific property called "upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate".

Prometheus successfully returns a response when querying this property as can be seen here:
[image: upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate in Prometheus]

However, the result consists of two time series (one with the upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate="12/11/2021" and the other with upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate="12/10/2021").

This becomes a problem as soon as I set up a singlestat in Grafana displaying the upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate label of the upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate query. This will lead to a "Multiple Series Error" as can be seen here:
[image: upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate in Grafana]

It works as expected if I change the
Grafana time range to e.g. "Last 15 minutes" as it can be seen here:
[image: upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate in Grafana with proper replacement date]

So my question is: Is there a way to select/extract only the time series with the most recent/latest label value for "upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate" so that, in this case, only the time series where upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate="12/11/2021" shows up?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help other people out as well: I resolved it by simply checking the "Instant" checkbox of the singlestat in the grafana dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is a system for working with numbers, and "12/10/2021" is a string rather than a number. If you can get the data exposed as a unix timestamp then you can use the `max` aggregator to get the highest value.

Comment: Thank you.
I now got it to work by simply checking the "Instant" checkbox of the singlestat. Also, this helped me out: http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/singlestat/#multiple-series-error

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to sort time series by labels and to select the first time series after that. But this can be done with [limit_offset](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#limit_offset) and [sort_by_label](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sort_by_label) MetricsQL functions. For example, the following query would return a single `metricName` time series with the maximum value for label `upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate`:

```
limit_offset(1, 0, sort_by_label(metricName, "upsAdvBatteryRecommendedReplaceDate"))
```