# Get the most recent timeseries in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am using Prometheus and grafana to monitor a certain metric (power consumption) of a program, in order to select this program, I have two query option :

- Using `pid` selector which will return just one time serie
- Using `cmdline` which takes a regex and return all processes matching this regex, this is what I am using.

If I run my program multiple times, it will create a different timeserie for each run in prometheus, so selecting using the `cmdline` selector : `metric{cmdline=~".*ProgramName"}` returns a vector of all timeseries (corresponding to all the runs).

My goal is to select the most recent run, thus I want to select only the most recent timeserie in that vector.

Below is a picture that explains this problem better :

[image]

In this picture, I have run the program for two times, I want to select the most recent timeserie only (the yellow one). Any help on how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't know how you could this using PromQL (but that doesn't mean that there isn't a way). The timestamp is a somewhat subordinate dimension in most time series databases. What do you intend to do with the most recent run's data? Absent use of aggregation operators across labels, these can be applied on per time series basis i.e. per process basis. Otherwise, you could use the HTTP API to grab the time series, find the one that starts|ends after the others and then code a function to process it.

Comment: Related question, though not with a satisfying answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025418/how-to-default-variable-list-of-dates-to-current-date

Comment: Solution with VictoriaMetrics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606429/895727